# Disable Android resource / image / PNG optimization

Tags: android, android-image, android-resources, android-build

How do I prevent the Android "build process" from optimizing .png images?

I have an Android project with the following res directories:

```
- /res/
- /res/drawable
- /res/drawable-hdpi
- /res/drawable-hdpi-v5
- /res/drawable-ldpi
- /res/drawable-ldpi-v5
- /res/drawable-mdpi
- /res/drawable-mdpi-v5
```

These directories **contain many .png files**. I optimize PNG sizes with PNGOUTWin, and the overall size is reduced by more than 20%. When I build the .apk file, the **images are "optimized" by the build process and the overall size is now 10% above the initial size**, or 30% above my/PNGOUTWin optimized size.

My goal is to reduce the .apk size, even if it will affect the final performance, memory requirements, etc. **How do I prevent the "build process" from optimizing .png images?**

I'm targeting Android 2.2 and above.

P.S.: I am currently building my Android project from Eclipse, but I will switch to the automated build later (Ant?).

**Note about JPG images:** JPG will not work, because they do not have transparency.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the Android documentation: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html#drawables

> **Note**: Image resources placed in res/drawable/ may be automatically optimized with lossless image compression by the aapt tool during the
>   build process. For example, a true-color PNG that does not require
>   more than 256 colors may be converted to an 8-bit PNG with a color
>   palette. This will result in an image of equal quality but which
>   requires less memory. **So be aware that the image binaries placed in
>   this directory *can change during the build*.**

*So if you want to reduce the size of your application you should either reduce the color-depth of your PNG files (this helps a lot) or switch to .JPG files wherever possible.*

Comment: 8-bit PNG files with alpha channel -- pretty shadows, many colors, size 200x200 looks ugly. Not perfect. Currently using Photoshop + Web Image Guru + PNGOUTWin postprocess.

Comment: Yes you cannot have gradient effects, shadow effects  etc.. as in PNG in JPG, so only I mentioned use jpg wherever possible.

Comment: Accepting your answer because indeed, images that looks nice in 8-bit PNG format are not optimized by the "build" process. However I ended up using Ant + 7-zip + original PNGs.

Comment: this answer does not answer the question at all, I don't understand how it got accepted

Answer (score 39):

Finally there is an official way to disable the PNG cruncher with Gradle which hasn't been mentioned here yet:

1. Edit main build.gradle to require gradle version 1.1.3 (or newer):

   ```
   buildscript {  
       repositories {  
           mavenCentral()  
       }  
       dependencies {  
           classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.3'  
       }  
   }
   ```
2. In the individual apps's build.gradle, section android {}, insert:

   ```
   aaptOptions {  
       cruncherEnabled = false  
   }
   ```

Reference:
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=65335

Comment: Wow this just cut about 1 min of build time for my debug builds

Comment: Is it possible to do it only for debug build? Maybe it can reduce build time

Answer (score 22):

Specifying PNG crunching is now a **BuildType** property and is disabled by default on debug builds:

```
android {
    …
    buildTypes {
        release {
            crunchPngs false // or true
        }
    }
}
```

**Note:** It's available from [Android Studio 3.0 Canary 5](https://androidstudio.googleblog.com/2017/06/android-studio-30-canary-5-is-now.html) .

Comment: Thank you. After a lot of time wasted your's only answer helped me.

Comment: Glade to helps you. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

**Android Studio**: Since Gradle Android plugin 1.0.0:

```
android {
...
  aaptOptions {
    useNewCruncher false
  }
....
}
```

**Eclipse**: Override the crunch task writing this in your build.xml:

```
<target name="-crunch">
   <echo message="This will skip PNG optimization"/>
</target>
```

Comment: I confirm that your Eclipse example also works with command line Ant-based workflow; by enclosing the code in `<project>` tag, and place them in `custom_rules.xml`, placed on project's root directory-- I originally thought the override wouldn't work (since PNGs won't be copied to `bin/res` folder), but it turned out that the toolchain would just use PNGs from original `res` folder in this case.

Answer (score 2):

```
 buildTypes {
        release {
            crunchPngs false // or true
        }
    }
```

add above the line on android block in

in ionic/Cordova project : root_folder_Of_App/platforms/android/app/build.gradle

in Android project: app/build.gradle

[image]

For More Information Visit: https://androidstudio.googleblog.com/2017/06/android-studio-30-canary-5-is-now.html

Answer (score 0):

Google recently introduced a [new PNG processor in aapt 0.9.1](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system) in the Android SDK Build Tools that fixes this issue of increased PNG sizes after aapt optimization.

With this update, it is now possible for Android Studio & Gradle to switch between the PNG processors with the following change in your build.gradle configuration file:

```
android {
    ..
    ..

    aaptOptions.useAaptPngCruncher = false
}
```

By adding this line, aapt uses the new PNG processor in which it checks to see if the "optimized" PNG files are smaller than the original PNG files. I was able to reduce 4.8 MB in my compiled APK and have not encountered any bugs/issues with the new build configuration.

UPDATE: This has been deprecated in later versions of Android Studio. Please refer to the answer provided by ChrisG.

Comment: I think thats obselete as of now, use the answer by @ChrisG