# Issue while upgrading the Android Studio to 1.0.2 from 0.8.9

Tags: android, android-studio

I just updated Android Studio from `0.8.9` to `1.0.2`, did the changes specified in the release document. Everything works fine except that I am getting the following error

> Error:(32, 0) No such property: useAaptPngCruncher for class:
>   com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.AaptOptions_Decorated

if I use

```
aaptOptions.useAaptPngCruncher = true
```

in gradle. Could anyone help me on this ?

Thanks.

Comment: yeah things changed from 0.8 to 1.x - looking for an answer myself...

Comment: You can find the answer you are looking for here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27369959/upgraded-to-android-studio-1-0-gradle-1-0-0-aapt-makes-png-images-larger-if-p

Answer (score 0):

In Android Plugin for Gradle 2.1.0 and above, use `cruncherEnabled` instead of `useAaptPngCruncher`.

Documentation [here](https://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/current/com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.AaptOptions.html#com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.AaptOptions:cruncherEnabled).