# Why is the image in my Flutter Android apk only 1x1 pixel?

Tags: android, flutter, apk

I have a 110x110 image in `android/app/src/main/res/drawable/notification.png` for my notification icon. When I `flutter run` this on my device, it displays correctly. However, if I `flutter build apk` and install the resulting .apk, my notification is a square white box. I've unpacked the .apk and the image at  `android/app/src/main/res/drawable/notification.png` is now 1x1.

I've tried `aaptOptions { cruncherEnabled = false }` and `release {crunchPngs false}`

Comment: Did you add the meta-data of notification icon in manifest?

Comment: @AmirMohammadShams no

Comment: <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
        android:resource="@drawable/notification" />

Comment: @AmirMohammadShams I'm not using firebase messaging. These are local notifications

Comment: Most likely one of the used [flutter] libraries also has a file of that name and thus overwrites your image. You should better use a different file name.

Comment: @Robert the actual filename is distinct to my app so that's not the cause.

Comment: `notification.png` is not distinct name. A different reason for the image to be changed could be the "image optimization" step: https://stackoverflow.com/q/12929884/150978

Comment: @Robert thx for the suggestion. From that link I tried adding `crunchPngs false` but I'm still getting 1x1 png files in the apk.

Comment: Can you replace your PNG file by something different that is not a PNG file? If it ends up with the same one pixel PNG file (same file content) your file is overwritten and not converted.

Comment: @Robert it's not being overwritten. This is something within the gradle build release chain. For now I've worked around it by extracting the app-release.apk, replacing the broken .png files with their originals, and then rezipping and re-signing the .apk.